# $(x+y)^a \le x^a+y^a$ for $x,y \ge 0$ and $0<a<1$

Tags: inequality

Trying to prove $(x+y)^a \le x^a+y^a$ for $x,y \ge 0$ and $0<a<1$.
I found one way, using derivatives:
The inequality is true for x=y=0 and the partial derivatives by x or y follow the same inequality.

My question is if this is a special case of something deeper than this game of derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be worth noting that, writing $y=cx$, for $c \geq 0$, the original inequality is equivalent to
$$
(1+c)^a \leq 1 + c^a,
$$
where $0 < a <1$, which is a more elegant inequality to handle.

Comment: Shai: This last statement of yours is highly debatable. Ironically, I remember reading somewhere that the first thing to do with inequalities similar to the one you suggest was to make them homogenous... hence going back to the OP's formulation.

Answer (score 2):

In any case, $u(x)+u(y)\le u(x+y)+u(0)$ as soon as $u'$ is nonincreasing as soon as $u''\le0$. (No *partial* derivative is needed here.)