# $(x+y)^r \le x^r+y^r$ when $r \in (0,1)$ and $x,y$ are real positive numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm sorry for the silly question, but I have a doubt. Given two positive real numbers $x,y$ and taking $0<r<1$, is it true that

$$
(x+y)^r \le x^r+y^r?
$$

In all the examples I considered, this turns out to be true. Moreover, to try to give a proof, does it suffices to prove that the function $f(z)=(1+z)^r-1-z^r$ is non-positive when $z \in (0,1]$ (i.e. taking $x>y$ and dividing by $x$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$(x + y)^s \le x^s + y^s$ for $0 < s \le 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168644/x-ys-le-xs-ys-for-0-s-le-1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54964, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155225/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233146, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49210, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264156

Comment: You can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem